# Gitlab-Runner Deploy to multiple servers

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I got following environment and setup:

- 3 load balanced production servers and
- one development server
- a working auto deployment to my development server with

  - one gitlab-runner which connects by ssh to my dev-server and pulls the dev-branch and
  - a gitlab-ci.yml which is limited to my dev-branch

How can I achieve:

- further auto-deploy to my development server if I push into my dev-branch
- auto deploy to my 3 production servers if I push into my master-branch

**The question is based on my current setup where following questions came up**

- can I let a gitlab-runner run just locally (also not in a docker container because I havn't installed one) so that its just up to the gitlab-ci.yml to differ on branches and deploy to the specific servers or
- can I install multiple gitlab-runners which are taking aktion on just specific branches?

or is there another solution which lets me achieve my plans?

Answer (score 6):

> *"Can I let a gitlab-runner run just locally (also not in a docker container because I havn't installed one) so that its just up to the
> gitlab-ci.yml to differ on branches and deploy to the specific
> servers"*

Yes, register local runners as [specific runners](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/README.html#registering-a-specific-runner-with-a-project-registration-token) with [Shell executors](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/shell.html) on the machines you want to deploy to so they can run local commands just like you use SSH now and only your specific projects can use them. Then take a look at the next sub-answer regarding [tags](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/README.html#use-tags-to-limit-the-number-of-jobs-using-the-runner).

> *"Can I install multiple gitlab-runners which are taking aktion on just specific branches?"*

Use either [tags](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/README.html#use-tags-to-limit-the-number-of-jobs-using-the-runner) to pin certain jobs to runners (e.g. your deploy job) or use [`only` or `except`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#only-and-except-simplified) to pin jobs to branches or
tags. (e.g. your deploy_prod job only run on `master` branch)

**Example `.gitlab-ci.yml` file (abstract):**

```
deploy-dev:
  tags: 
    - dev-runner
  only: 
    - dev-branch
  script:
    - cd mydir
    - git pull

deploy-prod:
  tags: 
    - prod-runner
  only: 
    - master
  script:
    - cd mydir
    - git pull
```

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer. If I take your "multiple deploy-stage" yml -> how do I now setup two different gitlab-runners (one for deploy-dev and one for deploy-prod) because they need to point to different servers or is this only possible for one local gitlab-runner and I have to differ the connection in the script-section of the yml?

Comment: You could / should register a runner on each of the hosts. As an alternative, you could indeed solve it in the script section.